# Is there an experience reward when the Pokémon you're trying to capture escapes?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've been lately noticing I've gained some experience when a Pokémon escapes from an encounter. It's only happened a couple of times, so I cannot be sure if it is due to the escaping or other things.

So, does this experience reward exist and how much is it? Is it something new? I don't remember noticing something like that before.

Comment: It's new I will have to find a Pokemon and if it happens to me then it may not be a glitch.

Comment: @TheMystery it's actually not new; it's been there since Day 1, but there's never been a notification. Your experience would change if you compared the before and after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has always been the case, but it only just now gets displayed.

You get 25 experience when a Pokémon escapes from you.

If you want a source, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4uc68u/psa_you_get_25_xp_when_a_pokemon_flees/) is one (dated July 24th).

> I learned this today when I had 74,999/75,000 exp for level 22 and I found a pokemon that fled. I then immediately leveled up and had 24 xp.